# Increase Huawei EC5805 wi-fi client limit

Tags: wireless-networking, router, 3g

Got a Huawei 3G modem with Wi-Fi router function. There's a Wi-Fi client number limit of 3, though. Is there's a known way to increase the limit? The existing article on Huawei B153 doesn't apply: the device doesn't even have an SSH service. Google search reveals mostly sales offers. Any pointers on the device's implementation details could help.
Version information as visible via its built-in Web console:

```
Software Version:   986.11.00.15.111SP01
Hardware Version:   WL1EC5805M
PRL Version:    32320
Device Name:    EC5805
```

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I increase the WiFi client limit on a Huawei B153?](http://superuser.com/questions/341928/how-can-i-increase-the-wifi-client-limit-on-a-huawei-b153)

Comment: that turns out to be a different incompatible device

Comment: Did you actually try anything from that other question, or just notice a different model number and assume its not related?  Please note the difference of effort put in by the author of that question.  What have you tried already?  What were the results?

Comment: There are no SSH interface there. I thoroughsly examined the article BEFORE submitting this question. But thanks for your concern.

Comment: No problem. to avoid this kind of thing, please include your research in your questions.

Comment: Extended the question as suggested.