# How can I increase Wi-Fi client limit on a Huawei router (WebCube by 3 Italy)?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wifi-configuration

I've got this Huawei WiFi router ("WebCube" sold by 3 Italy) that has a limit of 5 devices connected to it at the same time. I already found this: [How can I increase the WiFi client limit on a Huawei B153?](https://superuser.com/questions/341928/how-can-i-increase-the-wifi-client-limit-on-a-huawei-b153?lq=1) but unfortunately:

Calling `apply_submit( );` instead of clicking on save settings doesn't work. The router accepts it, WiFi restarts, but actually the value doesn't change (unless you change it to something <=5).

Solution provided by NoUsername MIGHT work, but I haven't succeeded. I found a `wlan_config.js` inside `wifi_advaned.asp` (or something like that... yes, `advaned` without `c`) with something related to max. devices connected. Changed from 5 to 50, 10, 9, 100 etc. but apparently doesn't make a difference and values greater than 5 still not accepted by the router.

Someone can explain me step by step how to perform the second solution since I'm quite a noob at this kinda things. I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong since this guy is not very detailed:

> When i entered something bigger than 5, i think it was immediately reset by some javascript, as far as i remember, or at least it was reset when you submitted these changes. So i dug in the JavaScript code of the site (with Chromes dev utils, which you get when pressing F12), and found that the submit method of the HTML form had this code somewhere which changes the value back to max. 5. I tried to change that and it sort-of-worked, the problem is that there is also some kind of ajax thing going on which constantly does some reloading and somehow messes with these manual edits, but after some trial and error, i was able to time it or stop it somehow, that it worked and it really submitted the other value (I think I set it to 10). After that it showed 10 when I visited that page (have not dared to touch it since).

I think I'm doing something wrong and changes at the code doesn't stick, because that guy said that he succeeded with a WebCube which is also my router.

To be more accurate:

I went to 192.168.1.1 and logged in (the router web page). I went to WiFi advanced settings, where I can change the number of devices connected up to 5. I pressed <kbd>F12</kbd>, then sources, js, `wlan_config.js`:

```js
if (parseInt(MaxUsersApply) > 5) {
  if (return_now) return false;
  alert(MACRO_WLAN_ASSOCIATIONONE);
  MaxUsers.select();
  return false;
```

Here I replaced `5` by a greater value (lets say 10). Then I wrote a value on the "max associated devices" field, for example 9, I went to the console, selected `wifi_advaned.asp` frame, and wrote `apply_submit();`, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>. WiFi restarts, but the value is still `5` not 9.

I'm using Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

The client limitation is in the sim card of the internet provider not in the huawei device router, so you can't do anything unfortunately...